# Magento2 with WorldPay Payment Gateway, Getting error "Payment failed, please try again later EXT_67: Unexpected Error"

Tags: payment, magento2, worldpay

I am using WorldPay payment method on my Magento2 store. I have tested it in the test environment and it's working as expected(Redirecting me to Worldpay site).
Now, I have changed the mode/environment to live and it's not redirecting to the Worldpay site. I am getting this error on the checkout page as:
"Payment failed, please try again later EXT_67: Unexpected Error".

I am using WorldPay Paypal method.
Please share your views here if you guys have faced this type of problem too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution to it?